# xmlstarlet does not work with end of string anchor $

Tags: xml, xpath, attributes, xmlstarlet

Using the xpath statement shown with xmlstarlet, it does not honor the end of string anchor, and selects both 'aaa' and 'bbb'.  How can do I structure the xpath statement to match on an attribute which ends with 998?

#### Xpath statement:

```
-v "../Property[contains(@Name, '998$')]
```

#### File object.xml:

```xml
<Object>
    <Property Name="1230-02324998">
        <Value>aaa</Value>
    </Property>
    <Property Name="3223-99824993">
        <Value>bbb</Value>
    </Property>
</Object>
```

Comment: `-v` and a path expression beginning with `../` on their own do not make sense. Please show a complete xmlstarlet command and show what you expect as the output.

Comment: Tried this:  
xmlstarlet sel -B -t -m "//Object" -v "..Property[substring(@Name, string-length(@Name) - 2) = '998']"

The answer should be:  "aaa", but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `contains` function does not have any regular expression support. Use `Property[substring(@Name, string-length(@Name) - 2) = '998']`.

Comment: xmlstarlet sel -B -t -m "//Object" -v "..Property[substring(@Name, string-length(@Name) - 2) = '998']" data.xml


Invalid expression: ..Property[substring(@Name, string-length(@Name) - 2) = '998']
compilation error: element with-param

Answer (score 0):

> Tried this: xmlstarlet sel -B -t -m "//Object" -v "..Property[substring(@Name, string-length(@Name) - 2) = '998']" The answer should be: "aaa", but it didn't work.

Please be careful when typing answers to your questions into the shell. Martin Honnen did not tell you to start the expression with `..`, which makes it an invalid expression.

Given that your XML input is stored in an XML document called "object.xml":

```
$ xml sel -B -t -m "Object" -v "Property[substring(@Name, string-length(@Name) - 2) = '998']" object.xml
aaa
```

Comment: Object is an XML element, not the filename.

Comment: @Inetquestion I know. But you did not tell us if you store the XML input in a file, nor its name. `object.xml` is just an example.

Comment: @Inetquestion Is your XML file stored in an XML document named `object.xml`? If not, you need to adjust the command. On your system, the `xml` command might be called `xmlstarlet` instead. - and yes, it is working for me.

Comment: Brain fart on my part... your suggestion works perfectly.  Thank you!